# HP Spectre x360 Kaby Lake: Ubuntu suspend not actually saving power

Tags: suspend, power-management, hp, battery, 16.10

Product Name: HP Spectre x360 Kaby Lake
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.10

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed on Hp Spectre x360 Kaby Lake, I have noticed that on suspending the machine isnt exactly saving power  - the battery discharge rate seems to be stable at the idle discharge rate?

Morover I have also noticed that the machine was a bit warm after a few hours, which makes me think that the machine was actually on but only the screen was off.

Any sugessions on how I can get the same suspend features as in Windows 10?

Comment: I'm not surprised, as Kaby Lake is quite new and kernel support isn't great yet. What kernel are you on?

Comment: $ uname -a
Linux x360 4.8.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Have you tried installing 4.9?

Comment: I have tired the following without any luck

uncommenting HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend in /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Not tired 4.9, may give it a shot after some risk assessment, since this my primary driver

Comment: Waiting for Ubuntu 17.04, fingers crossed will use kernel 4.10

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, this problem would be solved by adding `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and then rebooting.

In my environment, adding the line fixes the problem.

My environment: Ubuntu 16.10, HP Spectre x360 Kaby Lake

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
$ uname -a
Linux nek-HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible-13-ac0XX 4.8.0-41-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:27:17 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

For the detail, look at this bug: ["Notebook doesn't suspend when lid is closed after update to 16.04"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1574120)

Comment: I tried that, but no luck.