# HP Spectre X360 13 (i7-8565U Whisky Lake) won't suspend properly

Tags: suspend, power-management, hp, 18.10

I have an HP Spectre X360 with a Whisky Lake CPU that won't completely suspend. When it goes into suspend mode it looks like it is suspended (fans don't spin, power lamp is off, does not respond to mouse input/external input, etc.) but the machine seems to still be running and stays warm. The conditions appear close to identical to this post:
[HP Spectre x360 Kaby Lake: Ubuntu suspend not actually saving power](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870301/hp-spectre-x360-kaby-lake-ubuntu-suspend-not-actually-saving-power)

But adding `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend` like the answer there suggests did not fix or improve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bought same/similar machine in December and pulled my hair over same issues, eventually switched to Manjaro and all these got sorted out of the box.

From the little info I grabbed along the way:

_Suspend: this machine does not support S3 sleep mode, upgrading to kernel 4.19 or higher allows for hybrid suspend or hibernate modes which would result in similar outcome, zero power consumption, but it won't resume from suspend on lid open, you'd have to press power to retrieve your session. Couldn't figure out how to hook on lid open event to resume. Also, you may have to set a swap partition, I can't remember if that's necessary cause I created mine when I started to distro hop, so manjaro had a swap when installed, while ubuntu didnt and used a swapfile.

_If your model has Nvidia card, you should also have other issues under lastest Ubuntu such as erratic mouse, fans won't stop spinning even on idle, touchpad unusable etc. They all stem from some failed acpi management with the nouveau driver. Set nouveau.modeset=0 in grub, once in ubuntu install nvidia graphics driver 415 branch, and not the 39x one. Or even follow a tuto to install bumblebee; and remove nouveau altogether.

good luck

Comment: You led me to the answer! I installed the 4.19 kernel from the kernel mainline and it suspends perfectly now! I'm usually so active in turning on and off the machine I don't actually want to hibernate - so that's not a concern of mine; but the 4.19 kernel definitely fixed the suspend issue.

My machine is the one without the nvidia card (the middle range 13" model) so luckily blacklisting the nvidia module wasn't an issue for me; but I'm sure your reply will help someone else.

Comment: Swap partition or swap file have nothing to do with suspension, they're for hibernation and either one will do.

Comment: it seems something changed with the latest Ubuntu 20.04 update (not yet released at the time of writing). I tried `suspend` (from GNOME) and everything turned off including the power LED on the side, including wifi. Left it for the night and in the morning, it was cool as far as I can tell. Battery was 52% when I left it, it was 46% in the morning. More in the range of what I would expect in sleep S3 mode.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, `cat /sys/power/state` returns
`freeze mem`. However, `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` still only returns `[s2idle]`. But for sure, I now have a better _suspend_ than before in pre-Ubuntu 20.04. Before it was either no suspend (except for the screen to turn off) or the machine was crashing!